# Run cassandra cqlsh with python 3 on windows 10

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm trying to run the cassandra `cqlsh` command using python 3 on windows 10.

When I run the command I get this error:

```
cqlsh
  File "C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin\\cqlsh.py", line 248
    CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(HISTORY_DIR, 'cqlshrc')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is where the line is that it's complaining about in the script:

```
if hasattr(options, 'cqlshrc'):
    CONFIG_FILE = options.cqlshrc
    if not os.path.exists(CONFIG_FILE):
        print('\nWarning: Specified cqlshrc location `%s` does not exist.  Using `%s` instead.\n' % (CONFIG_FILE, HISTORY_DIR)
        CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(HISTORY_DIR, 'cqlshrc')
```

Cassandra seems to be running just fine, I just need a way to connect with it.

I'm on Python 3.8.3, and I would prefer not to downgrade to 2.7 if I can help it.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a better workaround for this issue , I have same problem as I have python 3.8 .
I user docker with CQL . Cassandra is hosted on my Linux box where python version is 3.8.
I install cqlsh thru docker and connect cassandra via docker

```
[root@localmonitor ~]# python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Aug 31 2020, 16:03:14)
[GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
[2]+  Stopped                 /usr/bin/python3
 docker run -it  --rm cassandra cqlsh 192.168.1.117
Connected to Test Cluster at 192.168.1.117:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.9 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

Answer (score 6):

Released version of `cqlsh` supports only Python 2.7, so it can't work on the Python 3.x.
Support for Python 3 will be only in the Cassandra 4, that hopefully will be released this year. See [CASSANDRA-15659](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15659), [CASSANDRA-10190](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10190), [CASSANDRA-15573](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15573) for more details.

Comment: Important to mention that Cassandra 4 is not supported on Windows, because the question is asking how to run on Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

As a working workaround you can install cassandra version 4.

It contains **cqlsh.py** file which works with **python 3.8.x**

The only one thing that I've done, - I've copied **cqlsh.bat** from cassandra version 3 to to cassandra version 4, because due to some reasons it is absent. (but thats only for windows users like me)

So, after it you just run your cassandra and then run cqlsh client from cassandra-version-4

Comment: I have trying this, but v4 cqlsh.py has a cqlshlib import, and from what I can tell, the pypi.org still modules are python 2.7.